# Read only property assignment error in Mongoose when launched with pm2

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, pm2

I'm using **pm2** to launch my **Express** app on boot **as a daemon**.

When I launch it manually from a shell session, there is no error. But when I use pm2 to launch it, I have this **Mongoose** related error logged in the log file:

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'toJSON' of object '[object Object]'
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/benoitlahoz/www/oz_modules/oz-mongo/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:74:34)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/benoitlahoz/www/oz_modules/oz-mongo/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/index.js:102:33)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
```

The workflow is:

- Launch `npm run start` with pm2 (using 'cross-env' and 'esm' modules): `export NODE_PATH=./node_modules && cross-env node -r esm index.js`
- Launch mongo server via 'child_process' module spawn
- Load custom modules through an `init` method
- [**ERROR** in oz-mongo module is appearing here, in Mongoose's '**validation.js**' file]
- Make custom modules listen to the Mongoose's 'connected' event
- On Mongoose 'connected' event register custom modules' schemas via `connection.model([Schema Name], [Schema Object])`

What could be the origin of this error, and what does this error mean?